# jdbcTemplate query row map date column generically

Tags: sql, spring, date, jdbc

I have a database with a date column, and when I perform a query I get each row as a Map of column names to column values. My problem is I do not know how to generically get the date column.

I am simply trying to cast it to a String at the moment, then parse it as java.util.Date, but this errors at the cast, and I am otherwise unsure as to how I can get the data?

This code is supposed to work with Sybase and Oracle databases too, so a generic answer would be greatly appreciated!

```
private static final String USER_QUERY = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, SUSPEND_START_DATE, SUSPEND_END_DATE FROM USERS";

public User readUsers(Subjects subjects) throws SubjectReaderException {
    /* Perform the query */
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(USER_QUERY);
    /* Map the returned rows to our User objects */
    for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
        String username = (String) row.get("USERNAME");
        /* Check if the user is suspended */
        if(checkUserIsSuspended(row)){
            continue;
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword((String) row.get("PASSWORD"));
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
}

private boolean checkUserIsSuspended(Map<String, Object> row) throws SubjectReaderException {
    final String startDateString = (String) row.get("SUSPEND_START_DATE"); // this errors
    if (startDateString != null) {
        final String endDateString = (String) row.get("SUSPEND_END_DATE");
        if (null != endDateString) {
            return checkDate(startDateString, endDateString); // this just compares the current date etc
        }
        /* Return true if the Suspended start date is not null, and there is no end date column, or it is null */
        return true;
    }
    /* Return false if the Suspended start date String is null - i.e. they have not been suspended */
    return false;
}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.SybTimestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will always give this error because you are casting the Object `com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.SybTimestamp` to String.

Why don't you make this check directly in the SQL instead of creating a filter? Something like

```
SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, SUSPEND_START_DATE, SUSPEND_END_DATE
    FROM USERS WHERE SUSPEND_START_DATE >= ?
```

and now you can use the `queryForList` passing as parameter the current time.

Another way for you to avoid this direct casts is using [RowMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html). This way you can use [ResultSet#getDate(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28java.lang.String%29)  and you won't be needing to cast anything as the JDBC driver will take care of the conversion for you :)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the RowMapper and `jdbcTemplate.query(queryString, new UserRowMapper())` as we want to keep the SQL generic, but it works like a charm!

Comment: Cool :D Glad I was able to help